# How to deal with additional arguments to a function based on which auxilliary function user chosed to use in the calculation

Tags: python, function, object

So basically I am writing my own library for analysis tasks, and I have a following problem, I will introduce you to it on a small scale since there is no need to explain it on 20 auxilliary functions.

Let's say that I have `5` functions in class `aux` and `2` functions in class `main`.
like this:

```
class aux:
    def foo1(self, a, b, c):
        return 'apple'

    def foo2(self, a, b, c, var1, var2):
        return 'apple'

    def foo3(self, a, b, c, var1, var2, var3):
        return 'apple'

    def foo4(self, a, b, c, var1, var4, var5):
        return 'apple'

    def foo5(self, a, b, c, var1, var2,  var4, var5):
        return 'apple'
    

class Main:
    def func1(self, a, b, c, calculation_tool: int):
        return 'tomato'
    
    def func2(self, a, b, c, calculation_tool: int):
        return 'tomato'
```

As you can see in class `Aux` functions have the same basic variables as inputs, those might be dataframes and others, but also these functions have individual variables that are need to calculate them according to the users wishes.

In the class `Main` there are two functions (all of my functions share the same architecture), user is meant to specify the auxilliary function used to calculation using `calculation_tool` variable.
(I've menaged this using dictionary to map functions)

Now ther is a problem since in real code I have 32 auxialliary functions and over 100 functions in classes that are equivalents to class `Main`.
I wouldn't like to list all arguments used in auxilliary functions into the class `Main` functions since it would be too long, and it would be very confusing.
How can I pass the arguments I need to these functions, but also inform the user that the function requires these specific arguments based on his choice of `calculation_tool`?

Example of function that uses an auxilliary func that user specified:

```
  def on_balance_volume(
        self,
        price_df: PandasDataFrame,
        n: int = 5,
        input_mode: int = 2,
        calculation_tool: int = 0,
    ) -> PandasDataFrame:
        """
    :param price_df: Dataframe that contains price data from which Accumulation Distribution Indicator will be calculated.
    :param n: Lookback period of On Balance Volume indicator.
    :param input_mode: Defines from what kind of data MA is calculated.
    :param calculation_tool: Defines MA function from which OBV is calculated.
    :return: DataFrame with calculated OBV.
    """
    _util = Utils()
    function, name = _util.choose_ma(calculation_tool)
    _change = _util.change(price_df=price_df, input_mode=input_mode)
    sign = _util.signum(price_df=_change, from_price=False, indicator_name="Change")
    product = pd.DataFrame()
    product["product"] = sign["Signum(Change)"] * price_df["Volume"]
    product_sum = pd.DataFrame()
    product_sum["On Balance Volume"] = product["product"].cumsum()
    obv_sml = function(
        price_df=product_sum, n=n, from_price=False, indicator_name="On Balance Volume"
    )
    obv_sml.rename(columns={f"{name}{n}": f"On Balance Volume SmL {n}"}, inplace=True)

    obv = pd.concat(
        [product_sum.reset_index(drop=True), obv_sml.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1
    )
    return obv
```

Comment: Your example makes no sense to me. How are the classes linked?

Comment: @roganjosh
Basically, I have classes like:
Utils,
MovingAverages,
MovingAveragesIndicators
TrendIndicators
VolumeIndicators
VolatilityIndicators
VolumeIndicators
MomentumIndicators
StatisticalIndicators
UncategorizedIndicators
MachineLearning

I use function from the first two classes and from StatisticalIndicators class for calculation of functions from other classes.
For example the arithmetic operations are the same as `x+y` but `x` and `y` may vary depending on which auxilliary function I use.

Comment: @roganjosh
I've added the example from the real code, this is one of the most simple, and short(lines of code) functions.

Comment: @roganjosh 
For example Moving Averages functions can take different arguments based on the function, most of them has the same variable names, but also each function may have different individual variables like:
`sc`, `fc`, `offset`, `sigma` and others. That are used in the calculation of particular chosed auxilliary function.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try function arg unpacking. In each of the main functions, you need to define a dictionary that maps calculation_tool to the auxiliary function with its arguments. In the main function, u need to use the calculation_tool to retrieve the function (With its arguments), then use the ** op to unpack all the arguments and pass them to the aux function

Try this code:

```
class Aux:
def foo1(self, a, b, c):
    return 'apple'

def foo2(self, a, b, c, var1, var2):
    return 'apple'

def foo3(self, a, b, c, var1, var2, var3):
    return 'apple'

def foo4(self, a, b, c, var1, var4, var5):
    return 'apple'

def foo5(self, a, b, c, var1, var2, var4, var5):
    return 'apple'
```

class Main:
def func1(self, a, b, c, calculation_tool: int):
tool_map = {
1: (self.aux.foo1, (a, b, c)),
2: (self.aux.foo2, (a, b, c, 1, 2)),
3: (self.aux.foo3, (a, b, c, 1, 2, 3)),
4: (self.aux.foo4, (a, b, c, 1, 4, 5)),
5: (self.aux.foo5, (a, b, c, 1, 2, 4, 5)),
}

```
    func, args = tool_map[calculation_tool]
    return func(*args)

def func2(self, a, b, c, calculation_tool: int):
    tool_map = {
        1: (self.aux.foo1, (a, b, c)),
        2: (self.aux.foo2, (a, b, c, 1, 2)),
        3: (self.aux.foo3, (a, b, c, 1, 2, 3)),
        4: (self.aux.foo4, (a, b, c, 1, 4, 5)),
        5: (self.aux.foo5, (a, b, c, 1, 2, 4, 5)),
    }

    func, args = tool_map[calculation_tool]
    return func(*args)
```